# a question about connected graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, path-connected

This is from notes

[image]

I don't understand how come $G_1$ is a connected component? It is obvious that $V_1$ cannot travel to $V_3$

Comment: It doesn't have to be a single edged walk. $v_1$ can travel to $v_3$ via the path $e_1,\ e_2$.

Comment: Perhaps a visualization will be helpful.  Imagine if you will that the vertices are beads and the edges are thread tied and knotted to the beads they are touching.  A connected component is the collection of things such that if you pick up a part of it, all of it gets picked up.  If you pick up $v_1$ then all of the beads $v_1,v_2,v_3$ and the thread connecting them all get picked up as well (*albeit perhaps dangling in the air*).  Having picked up the component with $v_1$ you will see that $v_4,v_5,\dots$ are all still lying on the ground, unaffected, are not in the same component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A connected component is a set of nodes and edges such that there is a walk (a set of edges) connecting any node to any other within the component.
So $G_1$ is a connected component since you can reach any $V_i$ from any $V_j$ for $i,j\in\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: Note that terms like "walk", "path" and "trail" are nonstandard terms and mean different things in different books/papers or to different people etc